# Limiting Text to spark textarea available size

Tags: text, textarea, limit

I'm trying to build a dynamically sized spark textArea which limits the possible text to its size.

E.g the textarea is set to width="300" and height="100". Now the user should only be able to enter or paste as much text as can be visible in the component. I don't want the textArea to scroll or linebreak if more text is entered.

I tried all sorts of approaches, but none with success.

Help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue but no perfect solution is found. But I found a simple workaround for this issue.

Spark TextArea has a textDisplay attribute of type IEditableText. by default, a RichEditableText component is assigned to this attribute. There is a property called contentHeight in this component. I used this property to determine if the text height exceeds textArea height. So my simple solution is like this:

```
protected function textArea1_changeHandler(event:TextOperationEvent):void { 
       if (textArea1.textDisplay is RichEditableText){
             if ((textArea1.textDisplay as RichEditableText).contentHeight > textArea1.height){
                     textArea1.maxChars = textArea1.text.length;
              }
              else {
                     textArea1.maxChars = 0;
              }
       }
}
```

Of cause, this needs to be fine tuned before using in an application. But I wanted to post the solution as soon as possible :) I will post exact logic required. But I think you can do it by your own too...

Answer (score 0):

for a Spark textArea I used this on each change of text:

while (textArea.textFlow.flowComposer.numLines>textArea.heightInLines)
     textArea.text = textArea.text.substr(0,textArea.text.length-1);